# Data structures equivalents of STL containers

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, equivalent

I study data structures and I want to ask what are the equivalents of STL containers.

for example

- vector = dynamic array
- queue = queue
- stack = stack
- priority_queue = heap
- list = linked list
- set = tree
- slist = single linked list
- bit_vector = vector bool
- map = pair
- deque = ?
- multiset = ?
- multimap = ?
- hash_set = ?
- hash_map = ?
- hash_multiset = ?
- hash_multimap = ?
- hash = ?
- bit_set = ?

Comment: deque = Double ended queue. Most like a vector where you can push_front the elements too. multi_set = Multiple values ( need not have unique values ); multi_map = A key can have multiple values associated. map != pair but map's container elements are pair.

Comment: `std::hash` isn't a container, it's a functor.

Comment: Steve : could you be more specific when u say it's a functor ?

Comment: @Jay: well, `std::hash` is a class template. Instantiations of `std::hash` are classes. Instances of those classes are callable. So all three of the template, the class, and the object, can reasonable be described as "a functor".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Concering the C++ standard library containers, the standard itself tries not to say too much about implementation. However, the very specific constraints on complexity of insertion, removal, look-up, range insertion and so on, mean that most implementations use the same types of data structures for the containers. Concerning some of your examples:

- std::list : *doubly* linked list
- std::set, std::multiset, std::map, std::multimap: self-balancing
  binary trees, typically red-blacktrees.
- hash_*: C++11 provides unordered_set, unordered_map and multi
  siblings. These are hash tables.
- bitset: fixed-size array

I believe the STL follows these implementations.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think qualifying std::map<> as just a "pair" would be correct. Actually, there is a *utility* named std::pair<> which is really only just a pair. std::map<> stores unique keys and non-unique values in a way that makes it possible to use a syntax similar to that of an array with indices being of types that can be numerical or not.

Edit: Corrected "container" to "utility" thanks to **juanchopanza**.

Comment: Pedantic note: std::pair isn't considered a container, but rather a "utility".

Answer (score 1):

set and multiset- binary search tree

map and multimap - binary search tree

deque - deque

the `hash*` containers are hashed associative containers implemented as hash tables.
eg. `hash_map` contains `pair<key,value>` which is looked up using hash table.

in bitset

`the individual elements are accessed as special references which mimic bool elements`

Answer (score 0):

```
vector = dynamic array  

queue = queue

stack = stack

priority_queue = priority queue based on binary heap 
                 priority_queue can be implemented using 
                 1. sorted array
                 2. sorted list ( unrolled list, skip list etc)
                 3. any other heap like Fibonacci heap, binomial heap

list = doubly linked list 

set = set based on AVL Tree ( usually ) 
      can implemented using any other binary balancing tree like 
      1. Binary Search Tree
      2. Red black Tree
      3. Splay Tree

slist = single linked list

map = map based on Red Black Tree ( usually ) 
      where every node is 'pair' structure
      can implemented using any other binary balancing tree like 
      1. Binary Search Tree
      2. AVL Tree
      3. Splay Tree

deque = deque

hash_set = set implemented using hash

hash_map = hash table

hash = 'Not Available', used as functor
```